# JavaScript two array in object deduplication

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to eliminate duplicate data by comparing two information in two arrays.

```js
const dataList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Kim", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
  { id: 2, name: "Lee", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
  { id: 3, name: "ji",  workcenterId: "workcenter0003", processId: "process0003" },
  { id: 4, name: "cho", workcenterId: "workcenter0004", processId: "process0004" },
];
const paramsList = [
  { id: 5, name: "kaka", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
  { id: 6, name: "eses", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
];

let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
  result.push(dataList[i]);
  for (let j = 0; j < paramsList.length; j++) {
    if (dataList[i].workcenterId === paramsList[j].workcenterId &&
        dataList[i].processId === paramsList[j].processId) {
      result.pop();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

My code many many not clean code..

I want a clean code.

I want short code.

sorry I ran the translator.
I'm curious about your clean code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get final result you want.

```js
    const dataList = [
      { id: 1, name: "Kim", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
      { id: 2, name: "Lee", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
      { id: 3, name: "ji",  workcenterId: "workcenter0003", processId: "process0003" },
      { id: 4, name: "cho", workcenterId: "workcenter0004", processId: "process0004" },
    ];
    const paramsList = [
      { id: 5, name: "kaka", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
      { id: 6, name: "eses", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
    ];
    const result = dataList.filter(dataItem => {
      return !paramsList.some(paramsItem => paramsItem.processId === dataItem.processId && paramsItem.workcenterId === dataItem.workcenterId)
    });
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry. I posted the wrong example. The other content is different, and I want to make sure that workcenterId and processId are the same.

Comment: Wow! That's how they use filter~  Thank you! I learned something new!!

Comment: @HyoD.k, I updated answer again using `filter` & `some`

Comment: ohoh!! **some** is very very Amazing! Thank you!!! I will study **some**!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference of the two lists by first figuring out how you want to serialize your data. Once you figure that out, you can use that function to cache your items for set comparison.

```js
const difference = (src, ref, serializeFn) =>
  (cache => src.filter(item =>
    !cache.has(serializeFn(item))))
  (new Set(paramsList.map(item => serializeFn(item))));

const serializeFn = ({id, name, workcenterId, processId }) =>
  JSON.stringify({id, name, workcenterId, processId });

const dataList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Kim", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "processId" },
  { id: 2, name: "Lee", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "processId" },
  { id: 3, name: "ji",  workcenterId: "workcenter0003", processId: "processId" },
  { id: 4, name: "cho", workcenterId: "workcenter0004", processId: "processId" },
];
const paramsList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Kim", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "processId" },
  { id: 2, name: "Lee", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "processId" },
];

console.log(difference(dataList, paramsList, serializeFn));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Wow... you're a master! It's still hard for me to understand... buy I'll study! Thank you!

Comment: @HyoD.k I fixed the output, I changed it to `!cache.has`...

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Kim", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
  { id: 2, name: "Lee", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
  { id: 3, name: "ji",  workcenterId: "workcenter0003", processId: "process0003" },
  { id: 4, name: "cho", workcenterId: "workcenter0004", processId: "process0004" },
];
const paramsList = [
  { id: 5, name: "kaka", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
  { id: 6, name: "eses", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
];

let result = dataList.filter(item => {
  return !paramsList.some(other => other.workcenterId === item.workcenterId 
    && other.processId === item.processId)
});

console.log(result);
```

or another approach:

```js
const dataList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Kim", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
  { id: 2, name: "Lee", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
  { id: 3, name: "ji",  workcenterId: "workcenter0003", processId: "process0003" },
  { id: 4, name: "cho", workcenterId: "workcenter0004", processId: "process0004" },
];
const paramsList = [
  { id: 5, name: "kaka", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
  { id: 6, name: "eses", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
];

const keysToRemove = new Set(paramsList.map(({workcenterId, processId}) => `${workcenterId};${processId}`));
let result = dataList.filter(({workcenterId, processId}) => !keysToRemove.has(`${workcenterId};${processId}`));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: WOW! Set..! It's amazing because it's a technology I've never used before! Thank you. You've been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to do that in a more cleaner way.

```js
const dataList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Kim", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
  { id: 2, name: "Lee", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
  { id: 3, name: "ji",  workcenterId: "workcenter0003", processId: "process0003" },
  { id: 4, name: "cho", workcenterId: "workcenter0004", processId: "process0004" },
];
const paramsList = [
  { id: 5, name: "kaka", workcenterId: "workcenter0001", processId: "process0001" },
  { id: 6, name: "eses", workcenterId: "workcenter0002", processId: "process0002" },
];

const result = dataList.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   const index = paramsList.findIndex(item => item.workcenterId === curr.workcenterId && item.processId === curr.processId);
   index === -1 && acc.push(curr);
   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```